# PHP - Can't access an array because "février" is not the same as "février"

Tags: php

I recently started working on a huge application, and while trying to squash bugs i encountered this error :

`Notice: Undefined index: février`

That appears on this loop of code, fetching data from a database :

```
    global $bdd;
    $result = array();
    $nbday  = GetDayOfWork($year, $pilote);
    $sql    = //a query, not important;

    $req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute(array($year, $pilote));

    while ($row = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row['month'] = utf8_encode(strftime("%B", mktime(0, 0, 0, $row['month'], 1, 0)));
        $row['taux']  .= "%";
        if (!empty($row['res']))
        {
            $row['res'] = ROUND((($row['res'] / 4) / 5.5) / $nbday[$row['month']]);
        } else
        {
            $row['res'] = 'non-d&eacute;fini';
        }
        array_push($result, $row);
    }
```

The problem seem to be coming from the $nbday array :

I displayed the array on my webpage, getting this :
`Array ( [avril] => 18 [f�vrier] => 20 [janvier] => 22 [mars] => 21 )`

When i use xdebug to check the var value i get this :

```
avril:"18"
février:"20"
janvier:"22"
mars:"21"
```

and finally, this happen : `$nbday["février"]  : null`

What's the matter ? i guess it has to do with the accent but what now ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Okay. After a lot of digging i found a solution; it's not always working but it solved this particular case:

In the PDO connection string, add : `new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;`